# How do I store a sorted set in Redux, and quickly sort it by various keys?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting, reactjs, redux

How do I store a sorted set in Redux?

Say I've got an ecommerce site with a ton of data, but the client only has a small subset of that data. I'm storing that data as an object (the keys being IDs), and the primary ordering as an array.

The problem is, when I add more and more unordered data, updating that array will take O(n^2) and be slow.

Naturally I'd use a sorted set, but I'm not sure how to implement that in Redux.

```
data = {
  <listingID>: <listingData>,
  ...,
  728: {
    name: 'Massive 1BR apartment in prime location',
    price: 4000,
    sqFeet: 1000,
    bedrooms: 1,
    location: 'East Village'
    datePosted: 1477496361164
  },
  1467: {
    name: 'Amazing 2BR steps from Times Square',
    price: 3950,
    sqFeet: 820,
    bedrooms: 2,
    location: 'Midtown',
    datePosted: 1427496322083
  },
  ...
}

order = [..., 728, 1467, ...]
```

Comment: Is it safe to assume you have the entire large dataset in the redux store at the time you wish to present the top 25 or so?

Comment: I don't have the entire dataset in the store unfortunately.

Think of the homepage of a real estate site. It'll only show the first 25 listings, but continue showing more as you scroll down. But then you can filter by certain variables (eg. 2BR only), and thus you're adding more unordered data to the giant object.

Comment: Ok.  The first part of the question (`Say I've got a large dataset in a Redux store`) seems to imply that you've got the whole thing in the store.  If you're only maintaining the top 25-ish in the store at any time and the sorting is done on the back end, then the speed issue probably has nothing to do with Redux, but becomes a Node + db + pagination issue.  If the user scrolls to make it 50 instead of 25 perf is still probably not an issue.  If you're concerned about the user only sorting what they've loaded, most users probably won't scroll enough to load a problematic amount of data.

Comment: Ok will correct the question. Maybe ignore the sorting thing. Basically I just want to be able to add random data to the set, and have the data structure holding the ordering automatically update. Essentially what I want is a sorted set (eg. sorted by date). Then I can have sorted sets for whatever ordering I want (eg. price, square feet)

Comment: I don't remember exactly which video it was, but DanAbramov covers this in his [Building React Applications with Idiomatic Redux](https://egghead.io/courses/building-react-applications-with-idiomatic-redux) video series, available free on egghead.io

Comment: Also see [Normalizing State Shape](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html) and [Managing Normalized Data](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/UpdatingNormalizedData.html)

Answer (score 1):

The standard approach to managing data in Redux is to store it in a "normalized" form, using as lookup tables with IDs as the keys.  To track ordering, use arrays of IDs.  These arrays can be constructed within your reducers and kept in the store, or derived as needed using "selector" functions.

I'd encourage you to read the new ["Structuring Reducers"](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/StructuringReducers.html) section in the Redux docs, which goes into further detail on this topic.

Comment: My concern with handling the ordering as arrays is that this could get really slow as you add more and more unordered data (O(n^2)).

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't worry about it unless you're talking about hundreds of thousands of items, and/or have proof that it's a legitimate performance issue.  With all perf questions, the real answer is to benchmark first.

Answer (score 0):

How I would approach this problem is to just do it at the component level, using local state and javascript's native .sort() rather than going back into the whole redux state / reducer.  I think this works especially if you have different datasets in your redux reducer vs local state.

I think there are some bugs in their code but here is Facebook's datatable with sort function: https://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/example-sort.html.